# Make Pact-Test fail on additional provider field

Tags: pact

The default behavior for a Pact test is to not fail when the provider adds fields to a message that the contract of the consumer does not specify, eg:

Consumer expects:

```json
{
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

Provider provides:

```json
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "hello": "world"
}
```

A Pact contract-test using the above noted messages would succeed. Is there a way to make them fail? Some "strict"-mode for example that requires exact matches of messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible according to the [pact docs](https://docs.pact.io/getting_started/matching/gotchas/#you-cannot-expect-a-field-to-not-be-present-in-a-response):

> ##### You cannot expect a field to not be present in a response
>
> Following Postel's law, the provider may return fields that the consumer will just ignore. The provider may have a pact with another consumer that requires those fields, so your consumer cannot tell the provider what it should not do. It can only specify what it should do.